# Text won't stay on screen

Tags: java, processing, display

I'm trying to code a simple space game in Processing. Here is the code:

```
float xPlayer, yPlayer; 
float xBullet, yBullet;
float xMoon, yMoon;
float ySpeed;
boolean gunShoots = true;
boolean drawMoon = true;
PFont font;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  ySpeed = 10;
  xBullet = xPlayer;
  yBullet = yPlayer + 30;
  xMoon = width;
  yMoon = random(0,height);
  font = loadFont("DINCondensed-Bold-48.vlw");  
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  circle(xBullet,yBullet,10); //gun
 
  if(keyPressed && key == ' '){
    gunShoots=true; 
  }
    if (gunShoots == true){
      xBullet = xBullet + 5; //gunshoots
    }
    if (xBullet > width){
      gunShoots = false;
    }
    if (gunShoots == false){
      xBullet = xPlayer +25; //gun resets
      yBullet = yPlayer +30;
  }
  
  if((key =='a') || (key=='d') || (keyPressed == false) || (key == ' ')){ //spaceship stays 
  drawPlayer(xPlayer,yPlayer);
  
  } else if((key == 'w')||(key == 's')){ //spaceship tilted 
  drawPlayertilted(xPlayer, yPlayer);
  }
  
  if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) > 30){
    drawMoon = true;
  } if (drawMoon == true){
    drawMoon(xMoon,yMoon);
    xMoon = xMoon - 1;
    
  }
  if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) < 30){
    drawMoon = false; 
    
    if (drawMoon == false){
      xMoon = -width;
      displayText(); 
    }
  }
}

  void drawPlayer(float x, float y){
  stroke(0); //spaceship
  strokeWeight(2);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  circle(x,y,50);
  fill(0);
  circle(x,y,20);
  triangle(x,y,x-8,y+25,x+8,y+25);
  fill(105,105,105);
  rect(x-20,y+20,40,5);
  rect(x-25,y+25,50,15);
  fill(255,255,0);
  triangle(x-25,y+25,x-40,y+35,x-25,y+40);
  triangle(x+25,y+25,x+40,y+35,x+25,y+40);
  fill(#F5F5F5);
  arc(x,y+40,50,20,0,PI,CHORD);
  }
  
  void drawPlayertilted(float x, float y){
    stroke(0); //spaceship
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(#F5F5F5);
    ellipse(x,y,50,35);
    fill(0);
    triangle(x,y,x-19,y+20,x+19,y+20);
    ellipse(x,y,20,15);
    fill(105,105,105);
    quad(x-15,y+15,x+15,y+15,x+20,y+18,x-20,y+18);
    quad(x-25,y+18,x+25,y+18,x+30,y+30,x-30,y+30);
    fill(255,255,0);
    triangle(x+25,y+18,x+40,y+25,x+30,y+30);
    triangle(x-25,y+18,x-40,y+25,x-30,y+30);
    fill(#F5F5F5);
    arc(x,y+30,60,20,0,PI,CHORD);
  }
  
  void drawMoon(float x, float y){
    stroke(107, 112, 120);
    fill(172, 175, 181);
    circle(x,y,50);// moving moon 
  }
  
  void displayText(){
    textFont(font, 30);
    fill(255);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("Winner Winner Chicken Dinner !!!", 250, 250);
  }
  
  void keyPressed(){ //spaceship movement
    if(key =='s')
    yPlayer = yPlayer + 10;
    if(key =='w')
    yPlayer = yPlayer - 10;
    if(key =='a')
    xPlayer = xPlayer - 5;
    if(key =='d')
    xPlayer = xPlayer + 5;
  }
```

So everytime the moon is hit by the bullet, I want a text to appear so the Player knows they've won the game.

```
if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) < 30){
    drawMoon = false; 
    
    if (drawMoon == false){
      xMoon = -width;
      displayText(); 
    }
```

However, the text only pops up for 1s exactly when the moon is hit, but it doesn't stay on the screen after the moon disappear. It would be great if someone can help me with this. Other feedbacks and comments on how I can improve the code are also welcome!

Thank you :)

Comment: Improvement: Why do 2 tests ? Isn't the following syntax enough 
if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) < 30){ xMoon = -width; displayText(); } –

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

In the `draw` loop, you continue to change the bullet and the moon's coordinates even though the game has been won.

Because of this, it's only a matter of time between this check `if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) < 30)` returns false, and the only place where you draw the "winner winner" text is inside that if.

You can fix this easily by modifying this part of your code:

```
  if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) > 30){
    drawMoon = true;
  } if (drawMoon == true){
    drawMoon(xMoon,yMoon);
    xMoon = xMoon - 1;
    
  }
  if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) < 30){
    drawMoon = false; 
    
    if (drawMoon == false){
      xMoon = -width;
      displayText(); 
    }
  }
```

and make it like this:

```
  // if drawMoon is false, no need to calculate the distance. If the distance is less than 30 pixels, no need to re-calculate it, we already know that drawMoon is now false
  if(drawMoon && dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) > 30){
    drawMoon(xMoon,yMoon);
    xMoon = xMoon - 1;
  }
  else{
    drawMoon = false; 
  }

  // once drawMoon becomes false, draw the text. Knowing that there is no place where we set it to true, it implies that it'll always be drawn from this point on
  if (!drawMoon){
    displayText(); 
  }
```

Please, note that I'm currently out of IDE and without the possibility to test your code. I'm sorry about that, yet I have reasons to think that it'll be ok.

Have fun!

Comment: Hi Laancelot, thank you for your answer :) I've fixed the code like you suggested but when I remove the condition of draw moon when it's false: `if(dist(xBullet, yBullet, xMoon, yMoon) < 30)`, it does not detect the collision when I shoot the bullet. I've thought of another collision detection by using the x & y coordinates but I also find that difficult. Really confused :(

Comment: heyy! nvm i made some mistakes fixing the code :) it works now! thank you :)